# JWT cannot be retrieved by HttpContext.GetTokenAsync in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, access-token, asp.net-core-2.1

This one really has me scratching my head as I can create a JWT.  I can add an attribute to authorize a controller and see if I do not add an 'Authorization' 'Bearer (token)' to a header it will return a 401 unauthorized.  However something as simple as getting the string of the token to get it's payload claims is not working.

So this works fine:

```
var token = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
```

This does not:

```
var token2 = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "access_token");
```

I have change the signature, hooked up the IHTTPContextAccessor in startup like so:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

I can see that the IHttpContextAccessor has values, as well as the authorization key.  I could have sworn this used to work easily in .NET Core 2.0 and now it doesn't.  Is there a simple hookup I am missing in Startup or Program?  At this point I am going to just get the data from Request.Headers.  But that just feels like a hack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1765) in ASP.NET Core 2.1 (fixed in the upcoming 2.2). The suggestion on the GitHub issue I've linked is to just extract the value from the header, as you're doing in your question. Once 2.2 is released and you're able to upgrade, you should be able to revert to using `HttpContext.GetTokenAsync`.

Comment: Yeah I looked up the link you gave and tried Haok's long winded thing like:  (await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)).Ticket.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token");  That still doesn't work even with wiring up the HttpContextAccessor in the controller and in the IOC of the startup.  Glad it's not just me doing something wrong.  That's weird they broke something like that though when I have stumbled upon more than a few sites that suggest that the 'HttpContext.GetTokenAsync'.  Guess I will just stick with getting the header,  thanks.

Comment: Tratcher confirms [further down in the chain](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1765#issuecomment-391421135) that HaoK's approach doesn't work too, FYI.